# Is it possible to have a List of different structs?

Tags: c#, list, types, struct

I would like to make a a `List` in which I can put multiple different structs. The problem is that I can't give the `List` the template argument, as the struct have no common denominator (and inheritance of structs isn't possible). I mean something of the following:

```
struct Apple
{
    float roundness;
    float appleness;
}

struct Orange
{
   float orangeness;
   bool isActuallyAMandarin;
}

List<???> fruitBasket;

void Main(string [] args)
{
    fruitBasket = new List<???>();
    fruitBasket.Add( new Apple());
    fruitBasket.Add( new Orange());
}
```

Leaving out the List's template argument gives, for obvious reasons, the error:

```
Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments
```

Is there a way of doing this? Perhaps with a `List` or perhaps with an array or different collection class that doesn't require the type argument?

**Edit:** This question is specifically about structs, *not* about classes. I am fully aware of the fact this could be solved with classes and inheritance, but I am simply not at the liberty to use classes instead (3rd party library issues...).

Comment: @rosko struct types cannot inherit other types, they can only implement interfaces, which is as good as boxing into `object` in the long run, only with the potential benefit of interface members.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but: structs don't support inheritance.

Comment: You can, as @DmitryBychenko says, have a `List<Object>` but this will incur a boxing overhead.

Comment: You could have a List<SomeInterface>, or have a non generic list. but both of them invoves boxing/unboxing overhead

Comment: Since you actually seem to want/need inheritance, consider using classes?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would want to use structs? Why not use classes?

Comment: Think of abstraction, have an abstract `Fruit` class and maintain its generic List.

Comment: I know that `struct` don't support inheritance, but when im saying this im sure that everybody knows that inheritance = use of classes.

Comment: Right. No inheritance support in struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's one class that's base for each structure: it's `Object`, so you can put it

```
  List<Object> fruitBasket;
```

but it means *boxing* each structure in the list. Yet another possibility is

```
  List<ValueType> fruitBasket;
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what boxing means? Is that bad, i.e. extra memory overhead or something?

Comment: it means you will have to fight another developer in the ring

Comment: @Yellow: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/csharp/HL1W121013-Understanding-Boxing-and-Unboxing-in-C

Comment: @DmitryBychenko the link is broken :(

Answer (score 2):

you can make use of interfaces here!

```
public interface IFruit {}

Apple : IFruit {...}

Orange : IFruit {...}

List<IFruit> list = new List<IFruit>();
list.Add(new Apple());
list.Add(new Orange());
```

Though, it would still cause boxing operation (interface being reference type)

Comment: He said 'inheritance of structs is not possible'. Don't you love it when someone answers by changing the question?

Comment: They do support interfaces (but not inheritance)

Comment: @Yellow Interfaces work just fine on structs. Though to be honest you have not addresses the question several here have asked. **Why** are you using structs to begin with? Why can't you use classes instead?

Comment: I have addressed it twice already (see the Edit in the post), it's a 3rd party issue. I guess wrapping their structs into a class would work, but it would be a lot of work (imagine putting 40 different Fruits in their own class) and I think it's not relevant to the question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility not yet mentioned is to define a structure which contains enough fields to encapsulate all the values that any of the desired structures could hold, as well as a means of determining how they should be interpreted.  For example:

struct AppleOrOrange
{
    float applenessOrOrangeness;
    int roundnessOrMandarinness;
}

Since there are certain bit patterns which will never be yielded by any operations on `float`, one could reserve two bit patterns for mandarin and non-mandarin oranges, and say that if `roundnessOrMandarinness` holds one of those bit patterns the element should be regarded as an orange; it holds the other, the value should be bitwise-converted to a `float` and the element regarded as an apple.  Note that in this particular case, this approach will save considerably on memory requirements versus boxing everything (boxing would more than double storage requirements in x86 [20 vs 8], and quadruple them in x64 [32 vs 8]).

An alternative approach if the majority of items are simple but there are a few complicated ones, would be to use a struct which contains the data for a "simple" item along with a reference type for supplemental information.  For example, if one has a list of drawing operations and the most common ones are "moveto" or "lineto", each of which just needs an `x` and a `y`, but some operations require more information, one could define a struct:

```
structure DrawListEntry {public int X,Y; public DrawOperation Op;}
```

For `moveto` and `lineto` entries, `op` would hold a reference to a singleton; for entries like `ShowBitmap`, it could hold a reference to a non-singleton object encapsulating arbitrary additional information.  If 90% of drawing entries are "moveto" or "lineto", this approach would require 12 or 16 bytes each for those rather than 24 or 32].  Cutting by half the storage cost of the majority of entries would be a big win.  Further, the cache performance of `var it=myList[index]; it.Op.Draw(it.X, it.Y)`, with `it.Op` identifying one of two singletons 90% of the time, may be better than calling `it.Draw()` on entirely-independent object instances.

Comment: Though I can see that your answer is technically correct, aren't you overcomplicating things a whole lot? This approach might be useful when we only have Apples and Oranges, but if we have 50 more fruits, all with different (number of) properties, this approach would be totally impractical. I believe Object Oriented Programming exists to make our life easier, not to get tangled in design patterns that you could easily get lost in. :-)

Comment: @Yellow: The original poster gave no indication I could see as to how many fruits there were, nor how varied they were.  There are many real-world situations for which this storage approach is a good fit, and many others where it is not.  The extended approach I suggested above--storing a couple of primitives and a reference to a possibly-singleton object--can offer huge performance gains versus using a separate object for everything, while remaining flexible.

Comment: Fair enough. You're absolutely right that my original question does mention larger fruit bowls, so this answer could suffice. I don't have a good idea of how much it costs to construct multiple different object versus your approach, but if you say this can be advantageous I'll believe you. :-)

Comment: altho this could work, this is overly complicated and will be a nightmare to maintain

Answer (score 0):

Although your question has been answered, i'll suggest you to also go through [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007947/c-sharp-abstract-struct) post of StackOverflow. It's going to make you clear about lots of stuff.

In C#, you can use interfaces to achieve something akin to polymorphism with value types (structs) as you can't derive directly from a struct but you can have multiple struct types implement specific interfaces.

Therefore, instead of your abstract struct, *Fruit*, you can have an interface, *IFruits*.

Comment: Where's the answer? I don't see it.

Comment: @rosko, a very bad answer is: *List<Object> fruitBasket;*, which has already been posted.

Comment: So this is not an answer Im wondering why not suggest using classes for this. Is this struct really necessary here?

Comment: @rosko, yes, actually :)

Comment: What I mean is that he can be unexperienced in programming and providing him better solutions for that he's planning may not be totally wrong. Your point is good. I don't wont him to force using classes instead of structs but I can't understand that this idea being downvoted.

Comment: ok if this is necessary then I gladly take a blame for trying to "force you" but in my answer i mentioned that if using `struct` isn't a must then there's always `class`.

Comment: @rosko, you're right dear. I'm sorry, i didn't mean that. i really didn't think of "*he can be unexperienced in programming and providing him better solutions*".

Answer (score 0):

No problem. You just make a List of Object. You can either use an old-fashioned non-generic ArrayList, the way we did back in the olden days of .Net 1.x, or a generic List. It works because object is the root of everything.

```
void Main(string [] args) {
  var fruitBasket = new List<Object>();
  fruitBasket.Add( new Apple());
  fruitBasket.Add( new Orange());
}
```

or

```
void Main(string [] args) {
  var fruitBasket = new ArrayList();
  fruitBasket.Add(new Apple());
  fruitBasket.Add(new Orange());
}
```

Getting things out of the list is another problem, but you didn't ask that, did you?

Comment: And what about `fruitBasket.Add("I don't belong here");`?

Answer (score -3):

You should try and use inheritance if `struct` is not one and only option for you:

```
abstract class Fruit {
}

class Apple : Fruit {
}

class Orange : Fruit {
}

List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>();
fruits.Add(new Apple());
```

and etc

Comment: I don't know why downvote, maybe he doesn't know that using classes and inheritance could be better here...? As i said this could be valid solution if `struct` isn't a must.

Comment: How does this help? `Apple` and `Orange` already inherit from `Object`, what's the benefit relevant to this question of adding `Fruit`? There's no indication in the question that Yellow wants to be able to access any members which are common between the two different fruit types.

Comment: I would delete this answer if I were you, its only going to get worse :)

Comment: The not so obvious benefit of 'type safety' since not all Objects are Fruits?

Comment: Then answer why struct > classes in this specific case.

Comment: don't give in to them, he should be using classes not structs, they are all wrong

Comment: @WeylandYutani It's got nothing to do with whether they're classes or structs. Either way this answer is useless.

Comment: only if the question is useless

Comment: But it would solve this problem and I don't see any good solution to this question right now. If you use `List<Object>` you can basically add ANYTHING to it.

Comment: id like to know why structs need to be used in this case

Comment: @WeylandYutani The question makes it very clear that there are no members in common between `Apple` and `Orange`. I agree that the list won't have much use without doing something nasty involving a lot of casting. But the correct response to an ill-conceived question isn't to just pretend the question was something different and answer that instead. All this answer is going to do is give a very confusing impression of inheritance and polymorphism

Comment: He said 'inheritance of structs is not possible'. Don't you love it when someone answers by changing the question?

Comment: @WeylandYutani: though I know I 'should' be using classes if I were a purist, one doesn't always have a choice. In this case (which I left out cause it's not relevant to the question) the structs are from a 3rd party and I simply can't change them. It's got nothing to do with not wanting to use classes.

Comment: @Yellow then mention this in your question that `class` is not an option because I was downvoted even that my answer would be valid for more of problems like this.

Comment: By the way, I can understand that in some cases (I would argue a minority), it might be worthwhile adding a type restriction to ensure that only certain types are added to the list. However: 1) This should be done with an interface, not a base class. 2) You should be very clear in your answer how the interface is being used, and how that differs from the normal usage of an interface for polymorphism.

Comment: In that case wrap the 3rd party structs in wrapper classes and have those wrapper classes use inheritance